# Injecting an api key to google script's UrlFetchApp for an HTTP Request

Tags: http, google-apps-script

**The Problem**

Hi. I'm trying to use Google Script's "UrlFetchApp" function to pull data from an email marketing tool (Klaviyo). Klaviyo's documentation, [linked here](https://www.klaviyo.com/docs/api/metrics), provides an API endpoint via an HTTP request.

I'm trying to use Google Script's ["UrlFetchApp"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html) to pull data from Klaviyo's API. Unfortunately, Klaviyo requires a key parameter in order to access data, but Google doesn't document if (or where) I can add a custom parameter (note, it should look something like: "api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". Note, it's quite easy for me to pull data into my terminal using the api_key parameter, but ideally I'd have it pulled via google scripts and added to a google sheet appropriately. If I can get JSON into google scripts, I can work with the data to output it how i want.

KLAVIYO'S EXAMPLE REQUEST FOR TERMINAL

```
curl https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics -G \
  -d api_key=XX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

THIS OUTPUTS CORRECT DATA IN JSON

Note: My ultimate end goal is to pipe the data into Google data studio on a recurring basis for reporting. I thought i'd get the data into a csv for download / upload into google data studio on a recurring basis. If I'm thinking about this the wrong way, let me know.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to convert the curl command to Google Apps Script? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `-G` flag, from the [curl man pages](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) (emphasis mine):

> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data,
>   --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. ***The data
>   will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.***

Given that the default HTTP method for [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) is "GET", your request will be very simple:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics?api_key=XX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```